how to have the viewbox keep its size?
In a wpf application, I have a user control with a Grid "ContentGrid" which can get bigger than the user control, then all the parents of ContentGrid are resized too big.
I do not understand why the Viewbox does not do its job and keep everything inside resized so one can see everything, with no resizing of controls outside it.
In particular, this user control "myUC" is placed inside another Grid, Inside a Window; when ContentGrid gets too big, the user control also gets too big, and the most parent grid overflows beyond the limit of the Window.
How to make sure the content of the viewbox won't resize its parents ?
Or how to make sure the most paretn Grid won't overflow the Window ?
<UserControl x:Class="myUC">
    <Grid>
        <Viewbox>
            <Grid Name="ContentGrid">

Simplified Window:
<Window>
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <myUC Grid.Row="0", Grid.RowSpan="1"/>


Why you don't set the width nor height of Viewbox nor UserControl explicitely?

@emoacht because they are resizable, like the Window

Do you want to make it to keep the given size, right?

Put the "UC" in the ViewBox, which goes in the Window. (You said the UC "gets too big").

By default, ViewBox works in both directions - enlarges and reduces. You can explicitly limit the direction of its work by specifying StretchDirection="DownOnly". ViewBox cannot always adequately resize its content if there is a control inside that is trying to grow.

@emoacht yes, I want the viewbox to adapt, not the rest outside it.

@Maxim, then we are narrowing the viewbox abilities; I prefer to have it work without getting bigger, or overflow its containing controls.

The way is to bind the viewbox's MaxHeight to user control's ActualHeight, so it never get bigger than the user control:
<UserControl x:Class="myUC">
    <Grid>
        <Viewbox MaxHeight="{Binding ActualHeight,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:myUC}}">

